# Is the HTML <base> tag also honored by scripting and CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, uri, relative-path

The [**base**](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/links.html#h-12.4) HTML element provides a base for relative URIs in the HTML. Must JavaScript and CSS also honor it for relative URIs issued in them:

E.g.

JavaScript:

```
location.href = "mypage.htm"`
```

CSS:

```
h4 { 
    background-image: url(myimage.gif) 
}
```

(in any browser?)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

CSS paths are always relative to the stylesheet itself and have no dependence on the HTML location (except when IE6 is buggy and stupid and tries to load `.htc` files specified in CSS `behavior` attributes relative to the document). For other stuff, `<base>` will affect the perceived current directory of the HTML as if the file was located in the directory defined by base. Consequently, it does affect things like `location.href=...;`. By the way, inline styles and style information in `<style>` element are loaded relative to the document location. Those are affected by the `<base>` tag, of course.

Answer (score 13):

The `base` tag is indeed only honoured by the relative links inside the HTML document *itself*.

There's however an IE6-specific bug which you really need to take into account when using `<base>` tag in HTML (not in XHTML). The `<base>` tag is in HTML documented as not having an end tag `</base>`, but IE6 incorrectly assumed it for true which will cause that the entire content *after* the `<base>` tag is placed as **child** of the `<base>` tag in its HTML DOM tree. This can cause at first sight unexplainable problems in Javascript/jQuery/CSS, i.e. the elements being completely unreachable in specific selections (e.g. `html>body`) until you discover that there's actually a `base` in between.

A normal IE6 fix is using conditional comments to include the end tag:

```
<base href="http://example.com/"><!--[if lte IE 6]></base><![endif]-->
```

Comment: @Marcus: It's not HTML4-valid (although browsers accept it). But in HTML5 you can perfectly do so.

Comment: @Marcus: Keep in mind that using `<base>` affects anchors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag/1889957#1889957

Comment: I know, I've changed a couple thousand of them :)