# Make ALL links / refs on a page point somewhere else

Tags: javascript, php, proxy

I am creating a simple web proxy (which you can see on [here](http://internal-sequence91.rhcloud.com/websiteaccess)) .
Everything is working OK except that resources on the target page, e.x `<script src="/js/myScript.js">` redirect to MY WEBSITE/js/myScript.js **which does not exist, because it was never meant to be ran on my proxy.**

How would I point all links / resources to be fetched through my proxy (I made  ascirpt that gets resources). All I need now is to make links / resources go there.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always the  tag. If you put it in the head and it will tell the browser what the base path for all relative URLs on the page is:

```
<head>
         <base href="http://awebsite.com/">
</head>
```

See a more detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12994681/2503170)